# Responsive images gallery bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, image-gallery, image-size

I am trying, a few days now, to make a gallery with images with slightly different size, but with the same layout.

As I can make it work in md view by forcing a 400px max-width for the container div, the workaround would create a gap below each image in xs and sm views.

What I want to achieve is have a gallery with images of same max-width and same max-height, and of course, not distorted.
http://www.bootply.com/qsy3HNl8DK

Non responsive layout example:

http://jsfiddle.net/npek7uxh/

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x610" />
</div>
```

Comment: your jsfiddle is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using some CSS media queries to target exactly the xs and sm views.
These are the sizes used by bootstrap:
- lg: >1200px
- md: >992px
- sm: >768px
- xs: <768px

So this code will target exactly sm and xs:

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
 img {
  margin-bottom:0;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The html is a bit convoluted, but you can do this without any custom CSS. In short, you combine `clearfix` with `visble-xs/sm/md/lg` to insert a clearfix to reset the row at the right spot, but only visible on specific devices.

i.e. you insert it after every 2 images on xs `<div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>` and every 3 images only for sm `<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>` and every 4 images for xs (because it's a factor of 2) and md and lg `<div class="clearfix visible-xs visible-md visible-lg"></div>`.

Example: http://www.bootply.com/6BkXDk68Cu

Comment: Clean for plane html but my galeries are dynamically generated and that would imply a bit of a headache in php.

Comment: fair enough. if you found something that works better for you, that's good